# cannot start ubuntu 18.04 after a forced shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

[first it shows the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGcM.jpg)

[then it shows these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVEYh.jpg)

[this is after I followed the instructions on line, but it failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0RP6.jpg)

[finally i stopped trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8oqy.jpg)

my computer has double systems, windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04, now ubuntu 18.04 cannot start. would someone help tell me how to start my ubuntu 18.04 without losing my former data in my computer. Great thanks!

Comment: Force shutdown?  I gather unclean (ie. you didn't use sysrq keys but forced via power-button; it;'s better if you clean shutdown via command or keystroke such as sysrq keys).  Have you booted a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` or file-system checked your disk?  The `fsck` error you provided failed because it was mounted, why a 'live' media is easiest (disk/ssd won't be mounted)

Answer (score 0):

To perform the fsck you must first unmount the device.

```
sudo umount /dev/sda8
```

After the device is unmounted from the file system then you may use the `fsck` utility.